# EmEditor not responsive when handling long lines

Tags: emeditor

I am processing text files with very long lines, like 1M characters, EmEditor doesn't handle it well.

Create a new HTML file, insert

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

then duplicate it while keeping it to a single line and duplicate a few times so that you can get a line with several millions of characters.

Now any use of arrow keys to move the cursor, dragging the horizontal scroll bar, clicking the mouse to change the position of the caret will make EmEditor freeze for a few seconds.

Is there any program setting to accelerate?

Comment: Which version of EmEditor are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update to the latest version of EmEditor, and select **No Wrap** on the **View** menu. You might also need to save the file first, and then reload the file.

If these don't help, you can disable highlight by selecting the **Text** configuration, and/or you can go to the **Optimization** page of the **Customize** dialog box, and select less than 10,000,000 for the **Do not highlight if line length exceeds** slider.

[image: EmEditor - Customize Optimization]

If you are working on HTML/CSS/JSON/XML files, you might also want to disable the syntax checker by selecting **(None)** for the **Syntax Checker Engine** in the **Syntax Check** page of the **Customize** dialog box.

[image: EmEditor - Customize Syntax Check]

You might also want to disable the **Highlight Matching Tag** and **Highlight Matching Brackets** options in **Highlight (2)** page of HTML configuration properties.

[image: EmEditor - HTML configuration properties - Highlight (2)]

Comment: I am using the latest version (20.2.2) with "No Wrap". The file (over 10MB in size, a one-line HTML) is saved on a NVME.2 SSD.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there any way to edit the huge line while enabling the syntax highlighting? I am dealing with minified HTML segments, with syntax highlighting turned off, the editing work is quite error-prone.

Comment: You might want to disable the syntax checker. I've updated my answer again.

Comment: I have disabled Syntax Check as you told while enabling syntax highlighting, EmEditor is still slow when moving the caret, scrolling horizontally or typing. (Turning off syntax highlighting restores the performance.)

Comment: If you have added any user-defined highlight strings using regular expressions, you might want to disable those. If the issue persists, please try `Reset All` on the `Tools` menu. If the issue still persists, please upload or send me your reproducible sample HTML file, and I will look into it.

Comment: A line with 1 million times of the HTML code I wrote in the original answer will reproduce the problem. If I move around the mouse pointer over the link, EmEditor will eat 100% time of one CPU core. In Process Hacker, I can see the top of the stack is ee256.dll!wmemstr+0x98, is it matching against some pattern through the whole string (a 10Mbyte one)?

Comment: I reproduced the issue. You might want to disable `Highlight Matching Tag` in `Highlight (2)` page of configuration properties.

Comment: With [Syntax Highlighting=On], [Syntax Checking Engine=None] and [Highlight Matching Tag=Off], EmEditor is still slow when dealing with long lines. I have restarted EmEditor to re-check the settings are effective. If the caret is in one place and I click the mouse to move it to another place, it takes about 1 second to see the caret repositioned. If I use arrow keys to move the caret, whenever a tag is met, it takes more time than moving through the inner text of the HTML tag. I've upgrade to version 20.3.1.

Comment: You might also want to disable the **Highlight Matching Brackets** option. I've updated my answer again.

Comment: I have turned off "Highlight Matching Brackets", but EmEditor is still slow when moving the caret. Very expensive wmemstr calls are still there.

Comment: If you haven't tried, please update to EmEditor v20.4 beta 1 (20.3.901), which improved the speed of moving the cursor while opening a very long line in HTML.

Comment: I am using Version 20.3.901 (20.4 beta?), but it's not faster than previous version.

Comment: Can you try v20.3.903 please?

Comment: 20.3.903 improved. There are still 2 things you can make it better: currently (1) if I click on, say, the 4000000th character, it takes 2 seconds to move the caret there and start blinking. (2) it takes up to 10 seconds if I move the mouse pointer to a URL to wait it to become hand shape and to become pointer when the mouse pointer leaves (<a href="http://aaa.com">xxx</a>, move the pointer over "aaa.com").

Comment: Please try v20.3.904.

Comment: 20.3.904 solved both problems. Keyboard navigation is smooth before first ~4M characters, after ~8M characters, it is quite slow when holding the arrow key to move the caret.

Comment: I optimized a little more on v20.3.908, but please be aware that you are editing a very long line. It won't become as fast as a short line. If you are satisfied with the optimizations so far, please accept my answer by clicking on the check mark beside it.

Comment: 20.3.908 is smoother than ever and smooth enough for me. Thanks a lot. Actually I don't really catch the idea why a long single line is more complicated that a very long segmented text. I guess that currently you render the text line by line, not characters by characters, so for rendering a long line, you have to run all patterns throught the whole line which is extremely long, instead of running on only the visible part, just like when rendering a segmented text.